# How to reuse "choice exception strategy" in mule

Tags: mule

In Mule flow how can I re-use choice-exception-stretegy across several flows?
I tried the following, but it throws error when I run mule application.

```
<mule ....>
<choice-exception-strategy doc:name="My_exception_strategy">
      <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException)"   doc:name="Strategy1">
      <logger message="message 1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      </catch-exception-strategy>
      <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(java.lang.Throwable)" doc:name="Strategy2">
      <logger message="message 2" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      </catch-exception-strategy>
  </choice-exception-strategy>

<flow name="Test1" doc:name="Test1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <logger message="message 3" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <outbound-endpoint ref="myendpoint" doc:name="MyEndPoint"/> 
    <exception-strategy ref="My_exception_strategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
    <set-variable variableName="somevalue" value="#[something]" doc:name="statusCode"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting when you try and run the app?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with the config you have posted.

1. There is a "set-variable"  after the exception strategy.  No other processors are expected after the "exception-strategy".
2. The exception strategy is not named. The attribute "name" is missing for the exception strategy.

Try the following flow .

```
<mule ....>
<choice-exception-strategy name="my_exception_strategy" doc:name="My_exception_strategy">
      <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException)"   doc:name="Strategy1">
      <logger message="message 1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      </catch-exception-strategy>
      <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(java.lang.Throwable)" doc:name="Strategy2">
      <logger message="message 2" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      </catch-exception-strategy>
  </choice-exception-strategy>

<flow name="Test1" doc:name="Test1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <logger message="message 3" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <outbound-endpoint ref="myendpoint" doc:name="MyEndPoint"/> 
    <exception-strategy ref="my_exception_strategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Hope this helps.